# No PowerShell Form datagrid selected

Tags: powershell

I have created a script that must select all the items in a powershell form, based on a variable. If the variable $bolCheckAllNumberedItems has the value '$False, then the grid should not be selected, in case the variable $bolCheckAllNumberedItems has the value '$True', the whole grid should be selected.

The code I have:

```
Clear-Host

$bolCheckAllNumberedItems = $True

$frmTest                                     = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
$btnOk                                       = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
$chkAllItems                                 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'
$DataGridForTest                             = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'
$InitialFormWindowState                      = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState'

$frmTest.Controls.Add($btnOk)
$frmTest.Controls.Add($chkAllItems)
$frmTest.Controls.Add($DataGridForTest)
$frmTest.AutoScaleDimensions                 = New-Object System.Drawing.SizeF(6, 13)
$frmTest.AutoScaleMode                       = 'Font'
$frmTest.ClientSize                          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(284, 261)
$frmTest.Name                                = 'frmTest'
$frmTest.StartPosition                       = 'CenterScreen'
$frmTest.Text                                = 'Test'
#
# btnOk
#
$btnOk.Location                              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(186, 220)
$btnOk.Name                                  = 'btnOk'
$btnOk.Size                                  = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
$btnOk.TabIndex                              = 1
$btnOk.Text                                  = '&Ok'
$btnOk.UseVisualStyleBackColor               = $True
$btnOk.add_Click($btnOk_Click)
#
# chkAllItems
#
$chkAllItems.Location                        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(22, 22)
$chkAllItems.Name                            = 'chkAllItems'
$chkAllItems.Size                            = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(104, 24)
$chkAllItems.TabIndex                        = 1
$chkAllItems.Text                            = 'Select all items'
$chkAllItems.UseVisualStyleBackColor         = $True
$chkAllItems.add_CheckedChanged($chkAllItems_CheckedChanged)
#
# DataGridForTest
#
$DataGridForTest.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = 'AutoSize'
$DataGridForTest.Location                    = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(22, 52)
$DataGridForTest.Name                        = 'DataGridForTest'
$DataGridForTest.Size                        = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240, 150)
$DataGridForTest.TabIndex                    = 0
$DataGridForTest.TabStop                     = $False
$DataGridForTest.ColumnCount                 = 1
$DataGridForTest.ColumnHeadersVisible        = $true
$DataGridForTest.Columns[0].Name             = "Number"
$DataGridForTest.Columns[0].width            = 100
$DataGridForTest.ScrollBars                  = 'Vertical'
$DataGridForTest.ReadOnly                    = $True
$DataGridForTest.AllowUserToAddRows          = $False
$DataGridForTest.AllowUserToDeleteRows       = $False
$DataGridForTest.AllowUserToResizeColumns    = $False
$DataGridForTest.AllowUserToResizeRows       = $False
$DataGridForTest.SelectionMode               = "FullRowSelect"
$DataGridForTest.MultiSelect                 = $true

#----------------------------------------------

$ArrayNumbers = @("one","two","three","for","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten")
[system.collections.arraylist]$ArrayWithHeader = @()
ForEach ($object in $ArrayNumbers)
 {
  $value = [pscustomobject]@{'Number' = $object}
  $ArrayWithHeader.Add($value) | Out-Null
  $value = $null
 }
$ArrayWithHeader | foreach {$DataGridForTest.Rows.Add($_."Number")  | Out-Null }

if($bolCheckAllNumberedItems)
 {
  $chkAllItems.Checked = $true
  $DataGridForTest.SelectAll()
 }

$chkAllItems.Add_Click({
if($chkAllItems.Checked)
 {
  $DataGridForTest.SelectAll()
 }
  else
 {
  $DataGridForTest.ClearSelection()
 }
})

$btnOk.add_Click({$frmTest.Close()})

[void]$frmTest.ShowDialog()
```

What is wrong with my code? Help is appreciated and with kind regards,
The Sting Pilot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way of doing this is to start your script with a small function you can call inside the checkbox `Click()` event aswell as in an added form event called `Add_Shown()`

```
function Select-Grid ([bool]$selectAll) {
    $chkAllItems.Checked = $selectAll
    if ($selectAll) {
        $DataGridForTest.SelectAll()
    }
    else {
        $DataGridForTest.ClearSelection()
    }
}
```

This way you can remove these lines:

```
if($bolCheckAllNumberedItems)
 {
  $chkAllItems.Checked = $true
  $DataGridForTest.SelectAll()
 }
```

and instead write

```
# call the helper function with the Checked value of the $chkAllItems checkbox
$chkAllItems.Add_Click({ Select-Grid $chkAllItems.Checked })
# this is an added event that fires when the form is first shown
$frmTest.Add_Shown( { Select-Grid $bolCheckAllNumberedItems } )
[void]$frmTest.ShowDialog()

# very important! dispose of the form when you are finished with it
$frmTest.Dispose()
```

---

An alternative approach is to again remove these lines:

```
if($bolCheckAllNumberedItems)
 {
  $chkAllItems.Checked = $true
  $DataGridForTest.SelectAll()
 }
```

and change the event `$chkAllItems.Add_Click()` to use a different event:

```
$chkAllItems.Add_CheckedChanged({
    if($chkAllItems.Checked) {
        $DataGridForTest.SelectAll()
    }
    else {
        $DataGridForTest.ClearSelection()
    }
})
```

Activate that event when the form is first shown and finish the code:

```
$frmTest.Add_Shown( { $chkAllItems.Checked = $bolCheckAllNumberedItems } )

[void]$frmTest.ShowDialog()

# and not forget to get rid of the form from memory
$frmTest.Dispose()
```

Using the `CheckedChanged()` method does not need an extra helper function as with the first approach.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. You have solved my issue. I have used your second option.